verbose boot message from systemd that delays for 1m30s, NFS mount for example
Using RHEL-8.10 x86-64, I have the network cable unplugged (purposely) and in /etc/fstab I still have
192.168.1.2:/data   /data   nfs   defaults  0 0

during boot, with the console being verbose per GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX not having rhgb quiet and having verbose instead I get

The verbose line item (from systemd?) showing the attempting mount of /data with a 1m30s time window
At some time in the middle of that, the end time changes to 1m38s but then the delay completes and the boot process continues successfully.  My NFS /data mount does not happen, which recognize and expect - I did not want to comment out that entry in fstab.


Why the change on the duration?  What causes that, for any other delays during boot which I have noticed?  It's not just for NFS.
Can I modify this timeout duration?  To either not happen, or to be something less infuriating when watching it and after 10s I am out of patience?
Is there a way to keep the default time duration, but a console keyboard entry that will kill that wait and proceed with the boot process?  Specifically this, as this delay example of NFS mount is not the only thing I run into; when I get delayed like this during boot (when you recognize it's not a problem) is there a way to kill this ~1m30s delay?
The worst is for those items, which I have run into, where the 1m30s duration keeps changing so the delay becomes infinite, and you have to power button reboot and then boot into single user mode to correct the problem.


You're running into NFS timeouts and retries, until NFS givres up on the connection to 192.162.1.2.
Check with man mount mount.nfs, adding _netdev to the mount options will delay the mount until the network comes up.
192.168.1.2:/data   /data   nfs  _netdev

Of course, you won't have access to /data until after the network comes up. You can check with mountpoint /data, which gives different results if /data is a mount point (mount has happened) or a direcrory (no mount yet).  man mountpoint.
